# Regain an original fractional numeric value that Excel has transformed to a date value

Tags: excel, date, formatting, numeric

I have an Excel workbook that contains numeric values and some of them have been transformed by Excel auto format feature into the date values. I do not know the original numeric values and neither do I have access to the .txt version of that file.

Is there a way to calculate the value from the date? For example, what value was substituted by Excel to get:  `08.01.2014`.

**This is not related to applying VALUE function to the date of changing cell format to "General."**

Comment: It is a different question. I know VALUE function and if I apply it: =VALUE(08.01.2014) I will get 41852. This is the post-formated value. I ned to know the original value that was formated into the date. I also know for sure that the original value was not "8.2014". It was in the range of 10 to 50.

Comment: I am sure this must not only be a guess. MS Excel has a built-in algorithm to convert a fraction into a date if it looks like a date. I work on the reverse algorithm. A company sent me an Excel workbook with data downloaded from the IT system (not. csv or.txt, which would be manageable by simply changing formats in the numeric columns). I am struggling to understand what values were there. There are lots of such cases and the values have 2 digits after the decimal separator. Examples are: 20.54; 12.30; 10.15.

Comment: Yes, but 0.5 is just 0.5 whether one uses 100/200 or 1/2. It is one and the same values. I hope it can be solved definitely. These are some of the data, and the bold parts are the problematic dates. I am trying to use the surrounding values to guess and figure out a formula of the reverse transformation.
20.39;
28.45;
**8.1.14**;
44.06;
31.32;
31.32;
**8.1.88**;
16.93;
**6.1.27**

Comment: A lucky strike that seems to work: =mid(text(I6;"d.m.yyyy");3;1)&","&mid(text(I6;"d.m.yyyy");7;2). This will result is someting like 8,14; 8,88; 6,27

Comment: I do not need to know the fraction. A resulting value is enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT#1:**

If the value '42248' has somehow gotten into **A1**, then in another cell enter:

```
=--TEXT(A1,"d.m")
```

to retrieve the **1.9**

Comment: My question is not about the date value that Excel has put instead of my original value. I will try to explain (sorry, English is not my native language). Somebody entered '1.9' in a cell. Decimal separator is not set to "." ("," in my case) Excel will interpret this value as a date and transfrom it to '09.01.15' while it will change the actual value to '42248'. Then another user tries to guess what was entered in the cell, but the user knows for sure it was not a date. Do you know how to restore '1.9' out of '42248'? Can I get the exact initial numeric value, what will it be: '1.9' or '9.15'?

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to apply it.

Comment: Thanks! I could apply it and get '1.9'. Now let's assume the 1st user entered '9.15'. Excel will generate the same date '09.01.2015' (while substituting the value by '42248'). So am I right one cannot say with an ultimate confidence which exact value '1.9' or '9.15' was entered? Right **"Maybe m.yy rather than d.m"**.

Comment: If several user inputs can map into the same "large" integer *(date)* then my technique cannot be used................if you like, I will delete the answer.

Comment: ** Gary's Student** - your answer is actually what I needed. However, I see that 2 **different** entries ('1.9' VS '9.15') lead to the same Excel interpretation. Thus I think I cannot restore the true initial entry.